# Local ReportViwer 2012 Deployment with ClickOnce

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, reportviewer, sqlclr

I have a C#.Net WinForm App that uses few reports, the dataset made local and shown by report.

So I am deploying this app with ClickOnce .

In Prerequisites I have set.

Report Viewer 2012 .

.Net 4.

SQL CLR x64.

SQL CLR x86.

That works fine on local computer but when client tries to install .

The setup throws an Error .

I got into depth and Found the installer , trying to install

```
***Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server Denali CTP3 x64  

Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server Denali CTP3 x86.***
```

Installer installed these and then try to install Reportviewer and ReportViewer throws error that it didn't install CLR Package ,

So when I went to microsoft website and manually download and install

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065

and then I can install the program as:

```
***Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server x86

Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server x64***
```

this install contains non Beta or final version and then if I try to install report viewer 2012 .
it installs without any error .

**so the problem is , CLickOnce Installer Installing old version of SqlCLr types and installing new Reportviwer.**

I had tried everything on my Development machine , every component is updated , all things to latest , Report viewer , clr types sql sever express data tools , everything updated and latest . but still getting this issue .

**Today I tried Vs 2012 Express on New VM and tried to deploy it and same problem,
Bootstrap installer , installing old version of CLR types and Clickonce installer throws error.**

Any solution for this problem.

its more then a month and I'm stuck on the issue.

Thanks

```
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string}
Property: [NTProductType] = 3 {int}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 6.2.0 {version}
Running checks for package 'Windows Installer 4.5', phase BuildList
Looking up path for special folder 'WindowsFolder'
Running check with folder 'C:\Windows\System32' and file 'msi.dll'
Attempting to find file 'C:\Windows\System32\msi.dll'
File version is '5.0.9200.16384'
Setting value '5.0.9200.16384 {version}' for property 'VersionMsiDll'
The following properties have been set for package 'Windows Installer 4.5':
Property: [VersionMsiDll] = 5.0.9200.16384 {version}
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsi' and value '4.5': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsXP-KB958655-v2-x86-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsiDll' and value '4.5.6001.22299': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsXP-KB958655-v2-x86-ENU.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x86.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsi' and value '4.5': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x86.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB958655-v2-x86-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsiDll' and value '4.5.6001.22299': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB958655-v2-x86-ENU.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x64.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsi' and value '4.5': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x64.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003.WindowsXP-KB958655-v2-x64-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsiDll' and value '4.5.6001.22299': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003.WindowsXP-KB958655-v2-x64-ENU.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\Windows6.0-KB958655-v2-x86.MSU'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsiDll' and value '4.5.6001.22308': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\Windows6.0-KB958655-v2-x86.MSU' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\Windows6.0-KB958655-v2-x64.MSU'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsiDll' and value '4.5.6001.22308': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\Windows6.0-KB958655-v2-x64.MSU' is 'Bypass'
'Windows Installer 4.5' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64) and Update for .NET Framework 4 (KB2468871)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client'
Read string value '4.5.50709'
Setting value '4.5.50709 {string}' for property 'DotNet40Client_TargetVersion'
Reading value 'ThisVersionInstalled' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Updates\Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile\KB2468871'
Read string value 'Y'
Setting value 'Y {string}' for property 'KB2468871Client_Installed'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64) and Update for .NET Framework 4 (KB2468871)':
Property: [DotNet40Client_TargetVersion] = 4.5.50709 {string}
Property: [KB2468871Client_Installed] = Y {string}
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40ClientKB2468871\dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40ClientKB2468871\dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40ClientKB2468871\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'DotNet40Client_TargetVersion' and value '4.0.30129': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40ClientKB2468871\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40ClientKB2468871\NDP40-KB2468871-v2-x86.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'Intel': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40ClientKB2468871\NDP40-KB2468871-v2-x86.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40ClientKB2468871\NDP40-KB2468871-v2-x64.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'amd64': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'KB2468871Client_Installed' and value 'Y': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40ClientKB2468871\NDP40-KB2468871-v2-x64.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64) and Update for .NET Framework 4 (KB2468871)' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Running checks for package 'Microsoft® System CLR Types for SQL Server® 2012 (x86)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Install' of registry key 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server 2012 RC0 Redist\SQL Server System CLR Types\CurrentVersion'
Unable to read registry value
Not setting value for property 'IsViewerInstalled'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft® System CLR Types for SQL Server® 2012 (x86)':
Running checks for command 'SqlClrTypes_x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi'
Result of running operator 'ValueExists' on property 'IsViewerInstalled': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Result of checks for command 'SqlClrTypes_x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi' is 'Install'
'Microsoft® System CLR Types for SQL Server® 2012 (x86)' RunCheck result: Install Needed
Running checks for package 'Microsoft® System CLR Types for SQL Server® 2012 (x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Install' of registry key 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server 2012 RC0 Redist\SQL Server System CLR Types\CurrentVersion'
Unable to read registry value
Not setting value for property 'IsViewerInstalled'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft® System CLR Types for SQL Server® 2012 (x64)':
Running checks for command 'SqlClrTypes_x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi'
Result of running operator 'ValueExists' on property 'IsViewerInstalled': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Result of checks for command 'SqlClrTypes_x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi' is 'Install'
'Microsoft® System CLR Types for SQL Server® 2012 (x64)' RunCheck result: Install Needed
Running checks for package 'Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Redist\Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime'
Unable to read registry value
Not setting value for property 'IsViewerInstalled'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime':
Running checks for command 'ReportViewer\ReportViewer.msi'
Skipping ByPassIf because Property 'IsViewerInstalled' was not defined
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Result of checks for command 'ReportViewer\ReportViewer.msi' is 'Install'
'Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime' RunCheck result: Install Needed
EULA for components 'Microsoft® System CLR Types for SQL Server® 2012 (x86), Microsoft® System CLR Types for SQL Server® 2012 (x64)' was accepted.
EULA for components 'Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime' was accepted.
Copying files to temporary directory "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD215A.tmp\"
Downloading files to "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD215A.tmp\"
(8/4/2013 12:41:57 AM) Downloading 'SqlClrTypes_x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi' from 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=221257' to 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD215A.tmp\'
Download completed at 8/4/2013 12:41:58 AM
Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD215A.tmp\SqlClrTypes_x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi
WinVerifyTrust returned 0
File trusted
(8/4/2013 12:41:58 AM) Downloading 'SqlClrTypes_x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi' from 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=221258' to 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD215A.tmp\'
Download completed at 8/4/2013 12:41:59 AM
Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD215A.tmp\SqlClrTypes_x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi
WinVerifyTrust returned 0
File trusted
(8/4/2013 12:41:59 AM) Downloading 'ReportViewer\ReportViewer.msi' from 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=217022' to 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD215A.tmp\'
Download completed at 8/4/2013 12:42:01 AM
Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD215A.tmp\ReportViewer\ReportViewer.msi
WinVerifyTrust returned 0
File trusted
Error: Setup has detected that the file 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD215A.tmp\ReportViewer\ReportViewer.msi' has changed since it was initially published.
(8/4/2013 12:42:09 AM) Downloading 'ReportViewer\ReportViewer.msi' from 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=217022' to 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD215A.tmp\'
Download completed at 8/4/2013 12:42:09 AM
Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD215A.tmp\ReportViewer\ReportViewer.msi
WinVerifyTrust returned 0
File trusted
Error: Setup has detected that the file 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD215A.tmp\ReportViewer\ReportViewer.msi' has changed since it was initially published.
(8/4/2013 12:42:11 AM) Downloading 'ReportViewer\ReportViewer.msi' from 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=217022' to 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD215A.tmp\'
Download completed at 8/4/2013 12:42:12 AM
Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD215A.tmp\ReportViewer\ReportViewer.msi
WinVerifyTrust returned 0
File trusted
Error: Setup has detected that the file 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD215A.tmp\ReportViewer\ReportViewer.msi' has changed since it was initially published.
```

Comment: Please post the log of the failed Clickonce installation.

Comment: hi i posted the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall any non-final versions of SQL Server and visit the prerequisites page again & double check the components.